# How to deal with big SQL dump files while creating a MySQL container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having a *"weird"* issue where `docker-compose up` gets stuck while try to import a *"big"* SQL dump file. The dump file is about 170MB so I don't know how big that is for a MySQL container. This is how my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    webserver:
      image: reynierpm/docker-lamp:latest
      dns:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - d:/Development/sources:/var/www/html
      depends_on:
        - mysqldb
        - mongodb
      restart: on-failure
    mysqldb:
      image: mysql:5.6
      healthcheck:
        test: "exit 0"
        interval: 1m30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
      env_file: .env
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      volumes:
        - d:/Development/applications/sourcesdb_dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      restart: on-failure
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:latest
      env_file: .env
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
      restart: on-failure
```

Nothing weird there as you may see. If I try to import the SQL dump file in a regular MySQL installation, for example a MySQL server running in a Centos server (no Docker container), it works.

My guess is something related to RAM memory or CPU assigned to the container but I couldn't find a way to assign more RAM or CPU to that container as per docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). Although my setup for Docker is 10GB of memory and 2 CPU (I think this is for the Moby VM)

[image]

Any ideas? Does anyone knows how to add more memory to that specific container in case that's the issue?

**UPDATE**

After a long 30~45min (not sure what exactly time since I went out and leave the Docker running) the table license was created. However I am still asking if there is a way to speed up this by setting some memory for such container.

Comment: When you say it gets stuck, what exactly happens? Does it take a long time to process, or is there some sort of error message? If there's an error it'd be good to see that here.

Comment: @bouteillebleu it takes a _looooooooooonnnnnngggggg_ I mean is more than 10 min on the same file and nothing happen, from that point I never ever see the next file processing|processed the logs stop right there and I can't start the application.